# Strange Output in Selection Sort using C++ min_element()?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, selection-sort

I have implemented this code myself for Selection Sort after understanding the logic. You can clearly see I have used C++ STL's `min_element()` to find the minimum element in the array. But the Output is Completely Wrong. It seems as if the `forward iterator first` for `min_element()` is not iterating. Can someone help me finding the underlying problem. Thanks in Advance !

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;

void Swap(int &a,int &b){
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
}


void SelectionSort(int arr[],int n){
    int Min;
   
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){

        Min=*min_element(arr+i,arr+n);
      
        Swap(arr[i],Min);
        
       
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
}

int main(){
    int arr[]={64, 25, 12, 22, 11};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    SelectionSort(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
11 11 11 11 11
```

Comment: Think about what `Swap(arr[i],Min);` does.  Is that swaping array elements?

Comment: Also, you are sometimes passing the same elements to `Swap`, which as written is wrong. Also, you are not implementing selection_sort at all.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `arr` to `{11, 22, 12, 25, 64}`? The result in this case is wrong but not completely wrong, and it demonstrates that you are in fact updating the first argument to `min_element`. (No, this is not an answer, merely a test of your "seems as if" hypothesis.)

Comment: You're aware that your "clever" swap is most likely much, much slower than the obvious one with a third variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem with min_element is

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    Min=*min_element(arr+i,arr+n); <-- here
    Swap(arr[i],Min);
}
```

it take the value of the iterated to element instead of a reference/iterator to it, try instead to do

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    auto Min=min_element(arr+i,arr+n); // iterator
    Swap(arr[i],*Min);
}
```

You will now find our that your Swap is also not working.